# Is there a way to convert .msg files to Pdf in the sys_attachment table in Service Now?

Tags: servicenow

I need to convert the .msg attachment files(Content Type : application/octetstream) in the sys_attachmemt table to pdf in service now. Is there a way I can do that using fix script? Any other possible solution suggestions would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for converting an MSG File to PDF. Either you use Microsoft Outlook to save MSG as PDF or you will have to try an automated tool. Both methods will help you to perform the conversion.

**1. Convert MSG File to PDF through MS Outlook**
If you only have one MSG file that has to be converted to PDF then you can use this method. You will have to apply the following steps to do the conversion.

Open the MSG file in your Outlook account that you want to convert.
Then go to the File tab present at the top-left corner of the page.
Click on the Save As option that appears in the File tab.
Then choose the location where you want to save the file and save the MSG file in HTML file format.
Locate the HTML file you have recently saved and make right-click on it.
Expand the Open With option and choose MS Word.
Now in MS Word, go to the File Tab and click on the Save As option.
In the Save As Type, choose PDF file format.
Finally, click on the Save button and your MSG file will be saved as a PDF on your computer.
You have seen that the above method is fruitful for those who only have a few MSG files to be converted. But for the batch MSG to PDF conversion, the above method will not be suitable. Therefore, you will need an automated to convert MSG to PDF in bulk with attachments.

**2. Use MSG to PDF Converter with Attachments Tool**
**Aryson MSG to PDF Converter**  is one such utility that will migrate all the data from the MSG file to the PDF with attachments. You can convert MSG files in bulk by adding all of them at once to the tool. The steps to convert MSG to PDF using a professional tool are as follows:-

Download the Aryson MSG Converter on your PC or Laptop.
Launch the Tool and choose the Multiple Files/Folders option.
Then click on the browse button to add multiple MSG files to the tool and then click on the Next button.
You can preview all the emails and folders with their attachments in the tool.
Choose the emails or folders that you want to convert as a PDF and click on the Next button.
In the Save As option, choose the PDF file format.
Select the path where you want to save the resultant PDF file.
Finally, click on the Convert Button and all your MSG file emails will be converted to PDF in bulk with attachments.

This article might help you.

[https://goldfynch.com/blog/2021/03/08/how-to-convert-an-msg-file-into-a-pdf.html#:~:text=Double%2Dclick%20your%20MSG%20file,%2C%20and%20choose%20'PDF'](https://goldfynch.com/blog/2021/03/08/how-to-convert-an-msg-file-into-a-pdf.html#:%7E:text=Double%2Dclick%20your%20MSG%20file,%2C%20and%20choose%20%27PDF%27).